# How fast is Javascript compared to Java?

Tags: java, javascript

Are there any tests that compare Javascript's performance with Java's?

UPDATE: Since everyone is asking why the hell this question, here is some context :)

As you all know - I hope - Javascript nowadays doesn't only reside in the web client but also in the web server with node.js.

It could also be run in mobile phones and dekstops with appcelerator and phonegap.

It could also be used substantially in the web browser to make the user experience first class like with desktop applications.

But Java could do these things too, running applets on the web client, and on mobile phones. It's also a language for the backend with many frameworks to choose between.

Since each one of them could almost/entirely replace each other in the mentioned area, I want to know the performance difference between them, for every case I described:

- Client: Java Applets vs Javascript
- Server: Java EE vs Javascript with Node.js + Express
- Mobile phones: Java ME vs Javascript with Phonegap / Appcelerator
- Desktop: Java SE vs Javascript with Phonegap / Appcelerator

I hope the context is more clear now.

Comment: What are you working on where these are two competing languages? Are you looking to use JavaScript outside of a web browser?

Comment: @John: See Node.js, V8, MongoDB....

Comment: This question is pretty ridiculous. What is the context you're interested in?

Comment: John is right, without some context, this question doesn't make much sense. There are areas where Java and Javascript can "compete" these days, but they are still few and far between. Use the right tool for the job!

Comment: They really aren't all that similar. Maybe SOME of the syntax but that's it.

Comment: I think you are asking "Hi, which do you prefer, juice or steak?"

Comment: @Danny Chen: If you reread my question I was asking: "Which one is faster to prepare, juice or steak".

Comment: @John Kugelman. Yes I am. Read where I am intending to use them, almost everywhere outside the traditional web browser.

Comment: This is a good question and I'm looking forward to the answer. Both Java and Javascript can be used for server-side logic. Those that think javascript==browser should think more broadly.

Comment: I was arguing about this on reddit a while back saying 'oh java! forever will be faster!' and I got smacked down by someone who writes compilers... seems like it won't be eternal. JS has gotten so much faster lately.

Comment: I just thought I'd point out that Node.js is far from the only server-side Javascript platform. Wikipedia lists lots of other ones here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Server-side_JavaScript_solutions.

Comment: i love this question!! for once, everyone will (hopefully,hehe) say `Java is faster` :D haha...

Comment: The person asking  predicted many things that are happening now (2015).
-Writing from the future O.o

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Java and JavaScript are both programming languages. Programming languages are just a bunch of abstract mathematical rules. Programming languages aren't fast. Or slow. They just *are*.

The performance of an application has nothing to do with the language. The most important factor is the application architecture. Then comes algorithmic efficiency. Then micro-optimizations. Then comes the quality of the compiler/interpreter. Then the CPU. Maybe a couple of other steps in between. The language, however, doesn't directly play a role. (And of course if you're talking about benchmarks, then also the particular benchmark plays a role, as well as how well implemented the benchmark is, how well run it is, whether the guy who performs the benchmark actually *knows* something about benchmarking, and even more importantly statistics. Also, the *precise* definition of what you actually *mean* by "fast" is pretty important, since it can also have significant influence on the benchmark.)

However, the language might indirectly play a role: it is much easier to find and fix performance bottlenecks in 10 lines of highly expressive, clear, concise, readable, well-factored, isolated, high-level Lisp code, than in 100 lines of tangled, low-level C. (Note that those two languages are only examples. I don't mean to single any one language out.) Twitter, for example, have said that with a less expressive language than Ruby, they wouldn't have been able to make such radical changes to their architecture in such a short amount of time, to fix their scalability problems. And the reason why Node.js is able to provide such good evented I/O performance is because JavaScript's standard library is so crappy. (That way, Node.js has to provide all I/O itself, so they can optimize it for evented I/O from the ground up. Ruby and Python, for example, have evented I/O libraries that work just as well as Node.js and are much more mature ... but, Ruby and Python already have large standard libraries, including I/O libraries, all of which are synchronous and don't play well with evented libraries. JavaScript doesn't have the problem of I/O libraries that don't play well with evented I/O, because JavaScript doesn't have I/O libraries *at all*.)

But if you *really* want to compare the two, here's an interesting datapoint for you: HotSpot, which is one of the more popular, and also more performant JVM implementations out there, was created by a team of guys which included, among other people, a guy named Lars Bak. But actually, HotSpot didn't appear out of thin air, it was based on the sourcecode of the Anamorphic Smalltalk VM, which was created by a team of guys which included, among other people, a guy named Lars Bak.

V8, which is one of the more popular, and also more performant JavaScript implementations out there, was created by a team of guys which included, among other people, a guy named Lars Bak. But actually, V8 didn't appear out of thin air, it was based on the sourcecode of the Anamorphic Smalltalk VM, which was created by a team of guys which included, among other people, a guy named Lars Bak.

Given that the two are more or less the same, we can expect similar performance. The only difference is that HotSpot has over a hundred engineers working on it for 15 years, whereas V8 has a dozen engineers working for less than 5 years. *That* is the *only* difference in performance. It's not about static vs. dynamic typing (Java *is* statically typed, but most JVMs and certainly HotSpot make no static optimizations whatsoever, all optimizations are purely dynamic), compilation vs. interpretation (HotSpot is actually interpreted with an additional JIT compiler, whereas V8 is purely compiled), high-level vs. low-level. It is purely about money.

But I am going to bet that for every pair of Java and JavaScript implementations where the Java implementation is faster, I can find another pair where the JavaScript implementation is faster. Also, I can probably *keep* the pair and just use a different benchmark. There's a *reason* the call the Computer Languages Benchmark Game a "game": they even *encourage* you right on their own page to play around with the benchmarks to make any arbitrary language rise to the top.

Comment: Thats why I asked "How fast is Javascript compared to Java?"

Comment: >> Java and JavaScript are both programming languages. ... Programming languages aren't fast. Or slow. << True. So given the context the question is about programming language implementations not programming languages.

Comment: Disagree. A lot of languages define features which by design can't be processed efficiently by todays CPU's. That's why java will in general perform faster than Smalltalk and well written C will in general outperform java. Also if a language has automatic memory management or not, and if a language has low-level data structures (byte[], structs in C) is important.

Comment: @R.Moeller - It is certainly true that a lot of language features make optimization difficult.  However, a (hypothetical) "really smart" compiler would still be able to translate (say) Smalltalk into optimal Java, and hence to machine code.  (If a human can do it, then a sufficiently advanced compiler can do it too.)  The fact that "today's CPUs" or "today's compilers" can't do this is fundamentally a limitation of today's technology .. not the language(s).

Comment: @StephenC: Actually, HotSpot *is* a Smalltalk VM, so, if Sun/Oracle had thrown all that money at Smalltalk instead of Java, then Smalltalk would be as fast as Java is today. (In fact, the commercial high-performance Smalltalks aren't that far away anyway.) Remember: when Java first came out, Smalltalks were *way* faster than Java. Heck, when the Self VM (which became the Animorphic Smalltalk VM, which became both HotSpot and V8) first came out, it was competitive with many of the *C++ implementations* available at that time, and faster than some of them.

Comment: Some languages are slower than others and this is a fact. A language featuring static dispatch and unboxed representation of objects (no implicit heap allocations) like C++ (or Rust if you care about safety) will be faster that a dynamically dispatched language with uniform representation of objects. The cumulative affect of optimizations unlocked by these features (Mainly inlining, constants propagation and dead code elimination) will makes a very noticeable difference especially with games and servers with high load. Java doesn't belong to that category of super fast languages but ...

Comment: ... Java doesn't belong to that category of super fast languages but is still fast compared to javascript. An object's property access can be done by calculating the sum of the pointer of the object and an offset and then dereferencing that. All the informations necessary are there because java is statically typed. Compare that to javascript where objects types are non existant so a property access may need to dispatch on a hashmap. You may say that JIT solves that problem by finding out objects types at runtime and creating virtual classes. But this is an additional overhead to start with ...

Comment: ... JIT doesn't work with all Js code but with the subset working with statically known properties of objects. At this point, you will be writing Java code in Js with the inconvenience that you don't have a good guaranty that you didn't messed up things. I have had a discussion with a friend and he said that many companies invested a lot in Javascript but the same apply to Java. My point is Java as a language is more optimize-able than Js except maybe when it comes to GC since Js implementations restrict themselves to single threading which may unlock some optimizations opportunities.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag -- Here's the *reason they call the Computer Languages Benchmark Game a "game"* -- http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/sometimes-people-just-make-up-stuff.html#name-game

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag -- *they even encourage you right on their own page to play around with the benchmarks* -- Here's some encouragement http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/for-programming-language-researchers.html

Comment: @nawfelbgh - It is not a fact.  It is an opinion.  You cannot measure the speed of a programming language, and that >>is<< a fact..

Comment: @StephenC Comparing languages performance directly is meaningless as you point out. But my point was that some languages are more optimizable than others and therefore will have faster implementations.

In your answer you said: "The only difference is that HotSpot has over a hundred engineers working on it for 15 years, whereas V8 has a dozen engineers working for less than 5 years. That is the only difference in performance. It's not about static vs. dynamic typing".

The point of my previous comments was to refute that and I gave as an example: object layout.

Comment: @nawfelbgh - You stated  <quote>Some languages are slower than others and this is a fact.</quote>.  Then you stated <quote>Comparing languages performance directly is meaningless as you point out.</quote>.  Can't you see the contradiction?  How can something be both a fact and meaningless?

Comment: @StephenC Yes, I see the contradiction. The sentence "Some languages are slower than others and this is a fact" is wrong but I can't edit the original comment to fix that. I should have said "some languages are more optimizable than others and therefore will have faster implementations" since that is my main message.

Comment: This couldn't be less true. If all languages operated the same way, there would only need to be one language. If languages were independent of performance, the same algorithm, implemented identically in two highly optimized languages would execute at precisely the same speed. This is absolutely not the case. And when your programs become large, they behave VERY differently than these 30-line benchmarks. A large C++ program will almost invariably outperform any garbage-collected or interpreted language, especially as the codebase grows in size.

Comment: @Robear: I am willing to bet that for every pair of C++ and, say, Java implementations of the same algorith you show me, I can find a pair of implementations for which the Java code is faster.

Comment: @JörgWMittag - Then you don't understand the actual differences between the languages. For example, Java checks the bounds of an array on every access. It's an unavoidable performance hit on a common pattern. C++ pointers do not.  Java sacrifices performance for safety and development speed. Java optimizations are also limited because JITting needs to be fast. C++ compilation can take hours. C++ can inline assembly, which is often done for algorithms. Java cannot. Java generics are awful compared to C++ templates. These are only some of MANY examples. Java is more balanced, but C++ is faster.

Comment: @Robear: I stand by my bet. Show me two pieces of idiomatic code in Java and C++ implementing the same algorithm, and I can find you a C++ implementation and a Java implementation for which the C++ code will perform slower. I think you vastly underestimate *how slow* a C++ implementation can be. E.g. AFAIK, Cint performs roughly a million times slower than code compiled by GCC.

Comment: @JörgWMittag - "Cint" doesn't exist in either C++ OR Java. And C++ is compiled using GCC, so what are you even talking about? Look, java is slower BY DESIGN because it's safe. Do something wrong in Java and get an exception. Do something wrong in C++ and you crash your PC. The difference is that Java constantly does sanity checks, which costs CPU cycles. And I'll gladly take your bet. Show me your fastest CRC32 code in Java and I'll show you the C++ to smoke it.

Comment: @Robear: I *still* stand by my bet. Give me the same algorithm implemented in idiomatic C++ and Java, and I can find you a pair of Java implementations and C++ implementations, where the Java implementation can execute the Java code of the algorithm faster than the C++ implementation can execute the C++ code of the algorithm. Again, you *really* underestimate *how* slow some implementations of C++ can be, and how fast some implementations of Java are.

Comment: @Robear: ""Cint" doesn't exist in either C++ OR Java." – Cint is an implementation of the programming language C++. So, *obviously* it doesn't "exist in Java", whatever that means.

Comment: @Robear: "And C++ is compiled using GCC" – This is wrong. C++ is a programming language. A programming language is a set of abstract mathematical rules and restrictions. It isn't compiled or interpreted, it just *is*. Compilation and interpretation are traits of the compiler or interpreter (duh!), not the language. Every language can be implemented by a compiler and every language can be implemented by an interpreter. Most languages have both compiled and interpreted implementations. (Including C++.) There is no such thing as "the performance of a language". There is only the performance of …

Comment: … a particular piece of code executed by a particular version of a particular implementation of a language on a particular version of a particular platform in a particular environment under particular circumstances. For example, most modern mainstream desktop CPUs have specific features intended for accelerating C-like languages and C++-like method dispatch, but almost no features for accelerating garbage-collected languages or Java-like virtual method dispatch. It is well known that virtual memory kills GC performance, but deactivating virtual memory and emulating it kills C++ performance. …

Comment: … So, how do make a fair benchmark? With VM? Without VM? With VM for C++ and without VM for Java? What CPU do you use for the benchmark? One optimized for C++? One optimized for Java? One optimized for both (which AFAIK doesn't exist)? One optimized for neither? If you use different CPUs for the benchmarks, how do you ensure that different performance is due to the different languages and not due to the different CPUs? If you use the same CPU, how do you make sure that different performance is not due to different optimizations in the CPU?

Comment: @JörgWMittag - A programming language is *_NOT_* a set of *abstract* mathematical rules and restrictions. It is a set of _very_ *specific* rules. The Java language specification, section 10.4, states, "All array accesses are checked at run time". There is no JAVA compiler or interpreter that can violate this rule. If it does, it's no longer compiling JAVA, it's compiling something else. For this reason, JAVA will ALWAYS be slower at array access than a language that does not have this rule. This is ONE of MANY examples that mark distinct differences between languages and their performance.

Comment: @Robear - Java implementation can elide array bounds checking if they can prove that the access cannot be out of bounds. Oracle (nee Sun) published [The Java HotSpot Performance Engine Architecture](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/whitepaper-135217.html) some time ago, which states: "The Java programming language specification requires array bounds checking to be performed with each array access. An index bounds check can be eliminated when the compiler can prove that an index used for an array access is within bounds."

Comment: @GregJandl - Ah that's cool. Yeah I think I got way too far into the weeds on this one. Compilers have to make decisions. Java favors safety, C++ favors performance. To say that performance is fully decoupled from the language is just not true: if your application favors performance, for example, all languages are definitely not the same, and I think that's really what I was trying to refute. You can go to a Chinese restaurant and order a steak, and it might be a decent steak, but if you really want a steak and you want it to be good, you should just go to a steak house :)

Answer (score 45):

I only have an anecdote to add: I've recently reimplemented a Java calc server (finance) in Javascript (nodejs v0.6.8). WRT development time, the Javascript implementation was a breeze compared to the original Java implementation with far fewer lines of code. It was a breath of fresh air, really.

The Javascript-based server is able to calc through 2.4k trades/sec whereas the Java server handles 400+/sec on the same hardware using less memory. I wouldn't attribute the speed increase to raw V8 vs. Java 7 performance but rather to the implementation. The Javascript implementation uses far fewer data structures, does an order of magnitude fewer method calls and takes a more straight-forward and terse approach.

Needless to say, I'm very happy with the performance of node.js. And this, coming from someone who was Java only for many (9) years.

Comment: I guess you are comparing now sync and async approaches but not Java vs Javascript. And Node.js being async definitely wins against sync tomcat servlets and libraries. But this is not because Javascript is faster, but because async is a better use of resources than sync.

Comment: What change in terms of performance do you expect if had to write another version of the program in Java? Do you think the performance of the program would increase substantially (in comparison to the first Java version) by the insights you got from the JavaScript version?

Comment: I had compared nodeJS with plain C performance in `number-crunching` applications. NodeJS was only 2.5 times slower than C.

Answer (score 34):

Here are some tests comparing Javascript (V8) and compiled Java:

- [32 bit](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u32/javascript.html)
- [64 bit](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/javascript.html)

They indicate that Java is generally faster<sup>1</sup>.  However, if you dig around with those pages and the linked resources, you will notice that it is very difficult to compare like with like.

Interestingly, Javascript does significantly better than Java (under certain conditions) for the "regex-dna" benchmark.  My guess is that this is because the Javascript regex engine is faster than the Java regex engine.  This is not entirely unsurprising, given the importance of regexes in typical Javascript applications.

<sup>1 - Strictly speaking, you cannot say that language X is faster than language Y.  You can only compare *specific* implementations of the respective languages.  And the site I linked to is clear about that ... if you care to go in via the front page.  However it is not entirely unreasonable to generalize from specific datapoints ... and the apparent of absence of contradictory datapoints ... that Java is typically faster than Javascript in computationally intensive tasks.  But the flip side is that that kind of performance is often not an objectively important criterion.</sup>

Comment: >> My guess is that this is because the Javascript regex engine is faster... << With the regex-dna JavaScript V8 #2 program source code is a link to "Irregexp, Google Chrome's New Regexp Implementation" http://blog.chromium.org/2009/02/irregexp-google-chromes-new-regexp.html

Answer (score 11):

Java, obviously.

Programmers love to compare execution speed like some sort of pissing content. It is just one metric, and the majority of the time, not the most important one by a long shot. Java is a language that has a mix of being fast enough for almost anything, but high enough level that you get stuff like GC, which you don't usually get in similar languages. Javascript is a dynamic closure language that is great for getting stuff done quickly (and for FP programmers stuck in an OO world ;-) ). There isn't much in the way of intersection in the spaces where either would be appropriate.

I'll stop pontificating now

EDIT: to address the edit in the post

Due to the way one writes idiomatic javascript (functions composed of functions), it lends itself surprisingly well to asynchronous programming, probably better then any other language of similar popularity. Node.js shines when it comes to a huge amount of short connections, so javascript is a really great fit for that sort of thing.

While node.js is absolutely drenched in awesome, being the new hotness really doesn't mean it is the best at everything, no matter what the hype says. If a java app is replaceable by node, chances are java wasn't really appropriate in the first place.

Answer (score 10):

Probably not, but it doesn't really matter.

Prior to Google Chrome's JavaScript JIT, Java would win over JavaScript as soon as the problem got big enough to overcome the load time.

Java should still roundly trounce JavaScript due to integer vs. float math. No matter how good the JIT it can't really make up for this.

WebAssembly will turn this on its head anyway.

Comment: PHP problem on Facebook got big enough, and then they compiled it. So...

Comment: Not necessarily true for your last point (maybe it was in 2010?). V8 will first compile a function with less optimizations and meanwhile track statistics on types, etc for several runs.

Say you're summing up all the numbers in an array. If V8 sees that previous values all were integers, it will re-compile the function to use integer addition machine code instructions (it is "optimistic"). If half-way through the array there is suddenly a string, it'll flip back to the less optimized version. So if you are consistent, it can be quite fast.

Comment: There's a great [talk from Vyacheslav Egorov](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_q6iw3h48s) from earlier this year that has an in-depth treatment of arrays in V8 (among other things).

Comment: Ah so they finally fixed that too. I guess this answer will slowly become less and less true as time goes on.

Answer (score 3):

http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/javascript.html

(Remember to look at the cpu column as-well-as elapsed secs).

According to the above link JavaScript as reality stands now is much slower for almost everything.

Comment: Java is using 2-3x times the memory in almost every case... doesn't seem fair

Comment: This benchmark is unfair. Most of java perf. is gained through multithreading. You can do multithreading in nodejs by means of new processes and piping. But this is missing in these tests.

Comment: @Stepan -- here's how you can contribute programs -- http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/play.html#contribute

Comment: All benchmarksgame links are broken because the pages moved to `debian.net`.  See: https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/fastest/javascript.html